# Are $\mathbb{C}(x)\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}(y)$ and $\mathbb{C}(x)\otimes_\mathbb{C}\mathbb{C}(y)$ integral domains or fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, tensor-products, tensors

**Question**

Let $\mathbb{C}(x)$ and $\mathbb{C}(y)$ be function fields of one variable. Consider $\mathbb{C}(x)\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}(y)$ and $\mathbb{C}(x)\otimes_\mathbb{C}\mathbb{C}(y)$.

(a) Determine if they are integral domains.

(b) Determine if they are fields.

**Answer**

For the latter tensor product, I am pretty sure that we can write the following isomorphism

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{C}(x)\otimes_\mathbb{C}\mathbb{C}(y)&\to \mathbb{C}(x,y)\\
x\otimes1&\mapsto x\\
1\otimes y&\mapsto y
\end{align*}

This shows that $\mathbb{C}(x)\otimes_\mathbb{C}\mathbb{C}(y)$ is both an integral domain and a field. However, I don't know what to do with the former tensor product. Any help/hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you think the map you've written is an isomorphism? What is the inverse map?

Comment: In general, I would approach a question like this by explicitly writing out the tensor product in terms of a basis and doing direct computation. You can get away with this because these are tensor products of vector spaces, which are quite well-behaved.

Comment: What is a basis for $\mathbb{C}(x)$?  I suppose we could use partial fractions?

Comment: For the first part, we could first consider the easier $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$. Is this a domain? or field?

Comment: @AndrewDudzik isn't the inverse map the same? Also, by writing explicitly, I found that both of these are IDs and fields but I'm pretty sure that they are not. I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: @AndrewHubery If we say $((a+bi)\otimes(c+di))\cdot((e+fi)\otimes(g+hi))=0$, then doesn't this give either $(a+bi)(e+fi)=0$ or $(c+di)(g+hi)=0$, which shows it is an ID? Similarly, we can write $((a+bi)\otimes(c+di))\cdot (1/(a+bi)\otimes1/(c+di))=1\otimes1$. Thus, it must be a field too but I am guessing it shouldn't be.

Comment: I think $1/(x+y) \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ but not in the range of your map on $\mathbb{C}(x) \otimes \mathbb{C}(y)$.

Comment: As $\mathbb C$ has basis $1,i$ over $\mathbb R$, we know that $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$ has basis $1\otimes1,1\otimes i,i\otimes1,i\otimes i$ over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is well-known that $\Bbb C\otimes_{\Bbb R}\Bbb C\cong\Bbb C\times\Bbb C$ as rings. You can write $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R[z]/(z^2+1)$ and then the tensor product is $\Bbb C[z]/(z^2+1)$, then you can apply the CRT. Or you can note $(1\otimes1)=(i\otimes i)^2$, and factor using difference of squares to get two zero divisors $1\otimes1\pm i\otimes i$, note the divisors are orthogonal idempotents (if normalized) and so correspond to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in $\Bbb C\times\Bbb C$.

Comment: Thanks @GEdgar for pointing out the element I was missing. Now I managed to showed that $\mathbb{C}(x)\otimes_\mathbb{C}\mathbb{C}(y)\cong\mathbb{C}[x^ny^m:n,m\in\mathbb{Z}]$, which yields that it is an ID but not a field.

Comment: @confused What does $(1+x)^{-1}\otimes1$ correspond to in $\Bbb C[x^ny^m:n,m\in\Bbb Z]$?